# When does a dense matrix have a sparse inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra

Many common systems in PDEs (finite element etc.) result in sparse matrices that have dense inverses. I was wondering, are there ever matrices which go the other way? In that the matrix itself is dense, but the inverse is sparse?

I.e. are there any problems were you might encounter

\begin{align} 
A x = b 
\end{align}

where $A$ is dense, and $A^{-1}$ is sparse? What would the significance of this be?

Comment: Of course if $A$ is a sparse matrix with dense inverse, then $A^{-1}$ is a dense matrix with sparse inverse.  I can't speak to whether this leads to any "natural" examples in the context of PDEs and such.

Comment: Yes, that was kind of the thought process that made me think about this. In some sense its the inverse problem, "Find the forcing that made this solution happen".

Basically finding a sparse inverse would indicate tremendous problem structure, and I was wondering if that ever happened in the wild.

Answer (score 2):

Matrices that come from finite elements tend to be sparse because they are discretizing a PDE that consists of local differential operators. Non-local problems (integral equations e.g.) would yield dense matrices. I'm not aware of any cases where a seemingly dense problem later turned out, for deep reasons, to have a sparse inverse; oftentimes it is obvious at the PDE level that you are discretizing the inverse of a local operator, so you refactor your equations to avoid this (as Omnom says in the comments).